# How do I get my site to scroll properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, safari

I am building a site with a js menu that loads content into a container div. The site works fine on desktop, and on the respsonsive mobile emulator on my desktop browser, but on my phone it doesn't scroll.

https://clippingpointmedia.co.za/cpm2019dev/

This is my main stylesheet:

```
/* CSS Document */

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #222;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa';
}
#container {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    max-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#page-content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
#loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #2693C1;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
 @keyframes spin {
 0% {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}
 100% {
 transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
#mobile-nav, .mobile-footer {
    display: none;
}
.side-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: -300px;
    width: 360px;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.side-menu {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu-toggle, .mobile-menu-toggle {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-image: url("../images/MenuButtonOpen.svg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.menu-top {
    height: 150px;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#mobile-cp-logo {
    background: url("../images/HomeIcon-light.svg") no-repeat center;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -30px
}
#cp-logo {
    height: 120px;
    max-width: 175px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background: url("../images/HomeIcon-dark.svg") no-repeat center;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
#pt-container {
    padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    width: 100%;
}
#prod-title, #digi-title, #event-title {
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #2693C1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2693C1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 66.66667%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: none;
}
.side-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.side-ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.side-ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#444 0%, #1c1c1c 100%);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.side-ul li a::after, .top-ul li a::after {
    float: right;
    content: url("../images/arrow-right.svg");
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: -20px;
}
.side-ul li a:focus::before, .top-ul li a:focus::before {
    float: left;
    content: url("../images/arrow-left.svg");
    padding-right: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.side-sub-ul ul, .side-footer ul, .mobile-sub-ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.side-sub-ul li, .side-footer li, .mobile-sub-ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
}
.side-sub-ul li a, .side-footer li a, .mobile-sub-ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.side-sub-ul li a, .mobile-sub-ul li a {
    color: #606060;
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 18px 0;
    margin: 7px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.side-sub-ul li, .mobile-sub-ul li {
    background-color: #ccc;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.side-footer li a {
    color: #273658;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
.show {
    display: initial
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.menu-item-tablet {
    display: none !important;
}
.wes-hi {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
.social {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.social a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px 0;
}
.mobile-footer a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.mobile-footer li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#totop-btn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1px 14px 7px 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
#totop-btn:hover {
    color: #2693C1;
}
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -9;
    background: url("../images/full-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Responsive Queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
/* Tablet View */

.menu-item {
    display: none !important;
}
.menu-item-tablet {
    display: block !important;
}
#content {
    margin-right: 0;
/*    padding-top: 10px;/*    height: calc(100vh - 10px);*/
}
.social {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top: auto;
    position:absolute;
}
.social a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.social a img {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
.mobile-footer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: 95%;
}
#totop-btn {
    bottom: 50px;
}
.side-footer {
    display: none
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 359px), (orientation: landscape) and (max-width:600px) {
/* Small Mobile View */

#container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#page-content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 138px);
    overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.side-nav {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -99999;
}
#mobile-nav {
    /*      position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.mobile-menu-toggle {
    height: 55px;
}
.top-ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#444 0%, #1c1c1c 100%);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-footer {
/*    vertical-align: top;*/
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
    .social {
    height: 63px;
}
.social a {
    padding: 4px 10px 0;
}
.side-sub-ul li a, .mobile-sub-ul li a {
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 7px 0;
}
}
```

And the relevant html:

```
<body>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="container" style="display: none">
        <div id="mobile-nav">
            <div class="mobile-menu-toggle" onclick="togglemobilenav()"></div>
            <ul class="top-ul">
                <div id="mobile-cp-logo"></div>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglemobilenav(); load_production()">Production</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglemobilenav(); load_digital()">Digital</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglemobilenav(); load_events()">Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="mobile-sub-ul">
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglemobilenav(); load_about()">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-tablet wes-hi" onclick="togglemobilenav(); load_news()">News</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglemobilenav(); load_contact()">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="side-nav">
            <div class="menu-toggle" onclick="togglenav()"></div>
            <div class="side-menu">
                <div class="menu-top">
                    <div id="cp-logo"></div>
                    <div id="pt-container" style="display:none">
                        <div id="prod-title">Production</div>
                        <div id="digi-title">Digital</div>
                        <div id="event-title">Events</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="side-ul">
                    <li><a href="#production" class="menu-item" onclick="load_production()">Production</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#production" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_production()">Production</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#digital" class="menu-item" onclick="load_digital()">Digital</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#digital" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_digital()">Digital</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#events" class="menu-item" onclick="load_events()">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#events" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_events()">Events</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-sub-ul">
                    <li><a href="#about" class="menu-item" onclick="load_about()">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_about()">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#news" class="menu-item wes-hi" onclick="load_news()">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#news" class="menu-item-tablet wes-hi" onclick="togglenav(); load_news()">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-item" onclick="load_contact()">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_contact()">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-footer">
                    <li><a href="#">&copy; clipping point 2019</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#terms" class="menu-item" onclick="load_terms()">our terms & conditions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#terms" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_terms()">our terms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#privacy" class="menu-item" onclick="load_privacy()">our privacy policy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#privacy" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="togglenav(); load_privacy()">our privacy policy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- content will be loaded here -->
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div class="social">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/clipping-point-media/" class="linkedin" target="_blank"><img src="images/li-icon.svg" alt="" /></a>
            <!--            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/clippingpointza/" class="facebook" target="_blank"><img src="images/fb-icon.svg" alt="" /></a>-->
            <a href="https://twitter.com/clippingpointza" class="twitter" target="_blank"><img src="images/tw-icon.svg" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHAc4aC70UAr4Qa_GFFNDUQ" class="youtube" target="_blank"><img src="images/yt-icon.svg" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/clippingpointmedia_/" class="instagram" target="_blank"><img src="images/insta-icon.svg" alt="" /></a>
            <ul class="mobile-footer">
                <li><a href="#">&copy; clipping point 2019</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#terms" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="closemobilenav(); load_terms()">our terms</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#privacy" class="menu-item-tablet" onclick="closemobilenav(); load_privacy()">our privacy policy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bg"></div>
</body>
```

I think it has something to do with the height of the #page-content div that I have set to min-height: calc(100vh - 138px) to compensate for the navbar at the top and the footer at the bottom.

Alternatively it may have something to do with visibility or positioning on the other elements. The layout of the site changes completely on smaller devices...

I've tried adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; to various elements, but even when I set it to all elements using * {} it still doesn't scroll.

I've read a dozen posts some of which point to position: fixed so i've tried switching to absolute positioning...

It seems like the whole page tries to scroll instead of the #content or #page-content div... i'm just at a loss! PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: [Please submit your code onto StackOverflow rather than linking to your website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: um can we see some code please

Comment: I've added my code, I just put a link as I'm sure people would want to be able to see the code working..?

Answer (score 0):

Add below CSS inside `@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)` in your `style.css` at line no `4030`. It'll unable your **parent scroll** and **disable your individual container scroll** and also you add an **individual footer** in each container. So I also hide all **container's footer** and visible only last container footer. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
#ascensorBuilding {
   overflow: auto !important;
}
#ascensorBuilding > div {
   position: static !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   height: auto !important;
   transform: none !important;
}
#ascensorBuilding > div .footer {
   display: none;         
}
#ascensorBuilding > div:last-child .footer {
   display: block;         
}
```

Comment: Should this be targeting my #container?

Comment: I tried it on #page-content #content and #container but it didn't make any difference...

Comment: No, this should not target your container. I try above CSS in your website its works. Can you add in your website let me verify the changes? Thanks

Comment: I've added it at line 374. None of my css files go to line 4030..?

This is the main stylesheet for the front page: https://clippingpointmedia.co.za/cpm2019dev/inc/style.css

Comment: Link not working return **This site can’t be reached** error.

Comment: The link works fine for me..?

I've added your code to that stylesheet, but i really don't know how it will work when there are no ascensorBuilding id's in my pages?